# Guzzle Pool in Symfony 2 - Dealing with future

Tags: symfony, future, guzzle

I am trying to use Guzzle pool in Symfony 2 application. I am thinking to use it because its capability of sending concurrent request at once.

However, since its async in nature I am not sure how can I use it as service in Symfony 2. Since return are not always immediate.

For example lets say I have service called Foo in Symfony which have method like this some what.

```
function test() 
{ 
    $request = $client->createRequest('GET', 'http://lt/?n=0', ['future' => true]);

    $client->send($request)->then(function ($response) {

        return "\n".$response->getBody();
    });

}
```

Now I invoke this service like this.

```
$service = $this->get('foo');
$result = $service->test();
echo $result;// does not work :( echoes out null
```

Is there any way to get around this problem. I really want to use Future since I need async feature.

Comment: Does `$response` has a `getBody()` method? Have you tried to `var_dump()` your `$response`?

Comment: Yes I tried that but that would not do any good. Since response is not ready by then.

Comment: I meant to `var_dump()` it just before `return "\n".$response->getBody();`

Comment: Response is fine that's not the problem issue is how to deal with React Promise in Symfony which I think what Guzzle uses under the hood.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Guzzle pool in PHP application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28238621/guzzle-pool-in-php-application)

Answer (score 0):

You have to deal with promises (futures) in your application or wait for results.

About your example: firstly, you don't return anything from `test()` ;) Because of that you don't get any `$result`. As I said before, you have to choose between two different ways here: 1) wait for HTTP call inside `test()` method and return the result itself, or 2) return Promise immediately and deal with it in your app (through `then()`, `otherwise()` and `wait()` in the end).

If you choose async way for the whole app, the code might look like this:

```
function test() 
{ 
    return $client->getAsync('http://lt/?n=0')
        ->then(function ($response) {
            return "\n".$response->getBody();
        });
}
```

And later:

```
$service = $this->get('foo');
$promise = $service->test()->then(function ($responseString) {
    echo $responseString;
});

$promise->wait(); // Here you get the output.
```

I slightly changed you code for Guzzle 6 (current version of Guzzle that should use in new projects).

BTW, Guzzle uses [its own implementation of promises](https://github.com/guzzle/promises), that isn't connected with React.