# Guzzle pool in PHP application

Tags: php, promise, guzzle, reactphp

I am trying to use Guzzle pool in PHP. But I am having difficulty in dealing with ASYNC request. Below is the code snippet.

```
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

    function test() 
    {
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();   
        $request = $client->createRequest('GET', 'http://l/?n=0', ['future' => true]);

        $client->send($request)->then(function ($response) {
            //echo 'Got a response! ' . $response;
            return "\n".$response->getBody();
        });

    }
    $res = test();
    var_dump($res); // echoes null - I know why it does so but how to resolve the issue.
```

Does anybody how can I make function wait and get the correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could return it it wouldn't be async in code style. Return the promise and unwrap it on the outside.

```
function test() 
{
   $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();   
   $request = $client->createRequest('GET', 'http://l/?n=0', ['future' => true]);

   // note the return
   return $client->send($request)->then(function ($response) {
       //echo 'Got a response! ' . $response;
       return "\n".$response->getBody();
   });   
}
test()->then(function($body){
     echo $body; // access body here inside `then`
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One other example I wanted to share using guzzle 6, postAsync and Pool.

```
function postInBulk($inputs)
{
    $client = new Client([
        'base_uri' => 'https://a.b.com'
    ]);
    $headers = [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer token_from_directus_user'
    ];

    $requests = function ($a) use ($client, $headers) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++) {
            yield function() use ($client, $headers) {
                return $client->postAsync('https://a.com/project/items/collection', [
                    'headers' => $headers,
                    'json' => [
                        "snippet" => "snippet",
                        "rank" => "1",
                        "status" => "published"
                    ]        
                ]);
            };
        }
        
    };

    $pool = new Pool($client, $requests($inputs),[
        'concurrency' => 5,
        'fulfilled' => function (Response $response, $index) {
            // this is delivered each successful response
        },
        'rejected' => function (RequestException $reason, $index) {
            // this is delivered each failed request
        },
    ]);

    $pool->promise()->wait();
}
```